# Multiple notifications instead of one

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I have a service that starts notification:

```java
public class Notify extends Service{
@Override
public void onCreate() {

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, 0);

    Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    Notification noti_builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setContentTitle("Title")
        .setContentText("Text")
        .setSound(uri)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
        .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    noti_builder.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(0, noti_builder);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

Service starts inside other class here:

```java
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancelAll();
Intent intent = new Intent(AddAlarm.this, Notify.class);
intent.putExtra("id", ID);
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(AddAlarm.this, 0, intent, 0);
manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, notifyDate.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

After execute this code multiple notifications show up. All are duplicates. I tried to change pending intent flag, but I got no satisfactory results. Any suggestions?

Comment: Solved: Instead of Service please use BroadcastReceiver. Everything works perfectly fine with this.